# Define css in () in jquery

Tags: jquery

How would I define css inside ()
I know this is a simple question but I can't find the answer.

I KNOW this is wrong...

```
if ('#Box' == .css('display', 'none')) {}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're looking for:

```
$('#Box').css('display', 'none')
```

This is actually changing the style of the elements matched by your selector (in this case `#Box`).  It is not the same as defining a new css rule although in simple situations, it has the same effect.

You can read values like this:

```
var currentDisplayValue = $('#Box').css('display');
if (currentDisplayValue == 'none') {
    // do stuff.
}
```

Comment: Wow. Why didn't I think of that.

Answer (score 0):

you could also do something like:

```
$('#Box').hide('fast');
```

or

```
$('#Box').slideUp('fast');
```